# why does this not work in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, error-handling

Can someone explain me why this does not work.

```
private void AdditionalLoad(List<PersonTypePerson> ptps)
    {
        using(var _context = new SPIS_Entities())
        {
            var m = (from ptp in ptps.Where(xx => xx.PersonID == _Person.ID)//_context.PersonTypePerson //
                     join pt in _context.PersonType on ptp.PersonTypeID equals pt.ID
                     join pta in _context.PersonTypeAttriubute.Where(p => p.active) on pt.ID equals pta.PersontypeID
                     select new { persontypeatribute = pta, availableatribute = pta.Attribute }).ToList();


            var x = from ii in _context.InformationItem.Where(p=>p.PersonID ==_Person.ID)
                    join pta in _context.PersonTypeAttriubute.Where(p => p.active) on ii.PersonTypeAtributeID equals pta.ID
                    select new { persontype = pta.PersonType, attribute = pta.Attribute, information = ii };


            var z = (from all in m
                     join fill in x on all.persontypeatribute.AttributeID equals fill.attribute.ID into ps
                     from fill in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new
                     {
                         persontype = all.persontypeatribute.PersonType, //fill.persontype,
                         available = all.availableatribute,
                         attribute = fill.attribute,
                         information = fill.information
                     }).ToList();

        }
    }
```

The funniest thing is that I get a query result from "m" and "x". When it comes to the point to make the left join ("z") it breaks and throws a nullException, object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: A stack trace might help. To me it looks that you are trying to join a list in memory (`m`) with a database query (`x`) which will probably result in that `x` gets executed first in the last query and the join in the last query is a join in memory. It might crash if `DefaultIfEmpty()` returns a collection with the *default* of an anonymous object. That default would be `null` and you are accessing it with `fill.attribute` and `fill.information` in the last `select`. But it's just a guess...

Comment: I thought, something like that might be a problem